# the difference between sql_autoload_register and　__autoload?

Tags: php

I always write like this:

```
function __autoload($className){
   if(file_exists($className)){
       include $classname . '.class.php';
   }
}
```

but I found some coders write like this:

```
sql_autoload_register(function($className){
   $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $className);
   require_once($className);
});
```

so,I want to ask the difference between sql_autoload_register and __autoload,thanks!

Comment: You you read the manual?

Comment: Sorry,I cannot understand it!

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP docs [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). The part in bold might give you more of an idea.

> Register a function with the spl provided __autoload stack. If the stack is not yet activated it will be activated.
>
> If your code has an existing __autoload() function then this function must be explicitly registered on the __autoload stack. This is because spl_autoload_register() will effectively replace the engine cache for the __autoload() function by either spl_autoload() or spl_autoload_call().
>
> If there must be multiple autoload functions, spl_autoload_register() allows for this. **It effectively creates a queue of autoload functions, and runs through each of them in the order they are defined. By contrast, __autoload() may only be defined once.**

*Edit:* This answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894585/710827