# ZF2 and DOMPDF autoloading issue

Tags: php, zend-framework2, dompdf, zend-loader

I am using Zend Loader from [here](https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendLoader) in my project and I am unable to configure Zend autoloader for the DOMPDF, working parallel to dompdf autoloader. Is there any way to set zend autoload to configure such that it fallback to  dompdf auotloader.

I see some example e.g using pushAutoLoader, but that seems its using Zend older version (v < 2 probably )

```
    require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php' );
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader('DOMPDF_autoload', '');
```

What is the alternative to pushAutoloader() , in ZF2 Loader ? I do not see any such method right now.

One more thing I cannot use `'fallback_autoloader' => true,` option as I am using php  5.3.1 which gives me error :

```
  `Call to undefined function Zend\Loader\stream_resolve_include_path()`
```

As it seems `stream_resolve_include_path()` is added in php 5.3.2

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a minor glitch , just found that the DOMPDF config file is using an obsolete way to register its autoloader e.g

```
if ( !function_exists("__autoload") ) {
  /**
   * Default __autoload() function
   *
   * @param string $class
   */
  function __autoload($class) {
    DOMPDF_autoload($class);
  }
}
```

and a fix would be just use the `spl_autoload_register` bcz [php spl_autoload_register vs __autoload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894538/php-spl-autoload-register-vs-autoload) and replace the above code with just one line, with minor update to autoload function

```
function DOMPDF_autoload($class) { 
  //don't check for namespaced files/classes   
  if(strpos($class, "\\") > 0) return;

  if($class=='UFPDF') return ;

  $filename = mb_strtolower($class) . ".cls.php";

  require(DOMPDF_INC_DIR . "/$filename");
}

spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
```

cheers :)

Comment: dompdf no longer uses this method to register its autoloader. In 0.6.0 the autoload functionality has been significantly improved. The 0.6.0 release is still tagged as beta, but it's as stable as the previous release (0.5.1) and we highly recommend you give it a try. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf